# mod rewrite and htacces path to file break

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hello I have problem with mode_rewrite:

My `.htacces`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Everthing is fine when I use url like `mydomain.com/register.html`. The problem is when I use urls like `mydomain.com/register/ultra-user.html` (with another `/`). Then my html template cant find file where I have stored file style.css. For example, my css file is stored in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/templates/style.css`

When I'm using url `mydomain.com/register.html`. path to css file in console google chrome is like `DOCUMENT_ROOT/templates/style.css` (it's ok!) but when I used the url `mydomain.com/register/ultra-user.html`. The path to the css style is changed to `DOCUMENT_ROOT/register/templates/style.css`. My url get another "register" part and then i my script can't find css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use absolute path. currently it look like you are using sort path like

```
templates/style.css
```

but instead of this use absolute path like

```
http://yourdomain.com/templates/style.css
```

Comment: Okey it`s work but using absolute path is not slower than short path?? In my think if we using absolute path we all redirect and serwer have to request self again. When we use short path serwer no, he have to back folder and then get file?? Im right or not?

Comment: @user2965619 absolute path is more better than the sort path in SEO friendly manner. and your thinking is totally wrong.